# Javascript Value in Object returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-objects

I'm doing an AJAX request with jQuery and trying to access the value in an object that is returned by the Post request , but when i try to use it like this `result.VideoCode` it shows `undefined` ( using console.log ) but when i do a `console.log(result)` it shows that there is an object and there is data in it

here is a screenshot

[image: JS object]

Any ideas tho why this is happening and how can i fix it ?

Update:// the server was returning an array of objects with a single object in it ... so that solved the mystery ... should have figured it out earlier

Comment: Only VideoCode returns undefined? Have you tried not using capital letters?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet or gist?  My guess is there's something else relevant happening in your code that we can't see.

Comment: Update:// the server was returning an array of objects with a single object in it ... so that solved the mystery ... should have figured it out earlier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot, `result` is an array containing one object.

You'd need to access it like:

```
result[0].VideoCode
```

which means: The first element of `results`, then from that object the `VideoCode` property.